# Alignment of current line number in Vim

Tags: vim

In Vim I am using relative line numbering and in my .vimrc have `highlight CursorLineNr ctermfg=LightGray` to make the current line number stand out a bit more.
I was wondering if it's possible to also change the alignment of the current line number? By default it's aligned to the left, but I would like to have it align to the right like the other numbers.

[image: The current line number is aligned to the left]

Comment: @shoe, that behaviour is hardcoded and can't be changed, no matter how much bounty you put on it. If you want it that bad, write it and send a PR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combination of `number` and `rnu` option will change the display of line numbers. If you have `nonu` and `rnu`, then the current line number will be aligned with other  (relative) line numbers, however, the current line number shows always `0`.

If you enable both `nu` and `rnu`, you got the display style as your screenshot. This cannot be changed.

For detail, pls check

```
:h number_relativenumber
```

Related info:

```
        The 'relativenumber' option changes the displayed number to be
    relative to the cursor.  Together with 'number' there are these
    four combinations (cursor in line 3):

        'nonu'          'nu'            'nonu'          'nu'
        'nornu'         'nornu'         'rnu'           'rnu'

        |apple          |  1 apple      |  2 apple      |  2 apple
        |pear           |  2 pear       |  1 pear       |  1 pear
        |nobody         |  3 nobody     |  0 nobody     |3   nobody
        |there          |  4 there      |  1 there      |  1 there
```