# How to align hybrid number in vim?

Tags: vim, neovim

The original beahvior of `:set num rnu` is:
[image: original]

But I want [image: instead] instead.

(The difference is the space behind the line number)

Comment: Perhaps `set numberwidth=1` is close to what you want? Probably won't work in the first few lines of the buffer, but later on it will get the effect you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no way to change it by an option.

Related questions:

[Current line number aligned to the left with number and relativenumber](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3516/current-line-number-aligned-to-the-left-with-number-and-relativenumber)

[Alignment of current line number in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46443872/alignment-of-current-line-number-in-vim)